# What do XML do as "src" in <img> tag, and how to get that image?

Tags: html, xml, image

As a part of Stack Overflow Winter Bash, I too got a hat. The thing is, I just wanted to save my pic, and found the hat, as an overlay, so I took a screenshot. But when I studied further about the hat, I found that it's not a normal image, and thus, even the media pane of "page  info" section of Firefox, is not recognizing it as an image. I couldn't even save that pic.

Later, I used some tools like Firebug, and found this;

```
<img width="137" height="134" style="display: block;" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3Ardf%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20height%3D%22134%22%20width%3D%22137%22%20version%3D%221.1%22%20xmlns%3Acc%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fcreativecommons.org%2Fns%23%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20xmlns%3Adc%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%22%20viewBox%3D%2227.125%2029%20137.75%20134%22%3E%0A%0A%3Cg%20transform%3D%22%20translate(19.976182752768793%2022.142908647051712)%20scale(0.7536437893157988)%22%3E%3Cg%20transform%3D%22translate(-137.8%20-503.8)%22%3E%0A%3Cg%20transform%3D%22translate(-340%20-622.5)%22%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23231f20%22%20d%3D%22m620.8%201228h-11c-2.2-4.2-7.6-5.2-13.9-5.2-4.7%200-8.9%200.5-11.6%202.5-24.2-11.2-35.7-27-35.9-27.2-0.5-0.7-1.4-0.8-2-0.3-0.7%200.5-0.8%201.4-0.3%202%200.5%200.8%2011.9%2016.4%2036.1%2027.8-0.8%201.3-1.3%203-1.3%205.2%200%208.3%206.7%2015%2015%2015s15-6.7%2015-15c0-0.7-0.1-1.3-0.1-1.9h10.1c0.8%200%201.5-0.7%201.5-1.5-0.1-0.8-0.8-1.4-1.6-1.4z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23414042%22%20d%3D%22m595.8%201240c-3.8%200-7.2-0.9-9.6-2.3%201.9%203.3%205.5%205.5%209.6%205.5s7.6-2.2%209.6-5.5c-2.4%201.4-5.8%202.3-9.6%202.3z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23231f20%22%20d%3D%22m609.9%201160c-5.9-11.1-17.3-18-29.8-18s-24%206.9-29.8%2018c-13.3%2025.3-37.6%2021.5-59%2021.5%200%2018.6%2024.9%2033.7%2043.5%2033.7%200%200%2023.5-9.8%2045.4-9.8s45.4%209.8%2045.4%209.8c18.6%200%2043.5-15.1%2043.5-33.7-20.7%200.1-45.8%204.1-59.2-21.5z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23cca650%22%20d%3D%22m550.2%201160c5.9-11.1%2017.3-18%2029.8-18s24%206.9%2029.8%2018c13.3%2025.3%2037.6%2021.5%2059%2021.5v-5.9c-20.7%200-42.2%203.7-53.9-18.4-6.6-12.6-19.8-21.1-35-21.1s-28.4%208.6-35%2021.1c-11.6%2022-32.9%2018.4-53.9%2018.4v5.9c20.7%200.1%2045.7%204.1%2059.2-21.5z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Cg%20fill%3D%22%23d1d3d4%22%3E%0A%3Cpath%20d%3D%22m588.6%201180-0.9%203.2c-0.1%200.4-0.5%200.6-0.8%200.6h-2.4v1.6c0%200.5-0.4%200.9-0.9%200.9s-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-1.6h-1.8v1.6c0%200.5-0.4%200.9-0.9%200.9s-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-1.6h-1.8v1.6c0%200.5-0.4%200.9-0.9%200.9s-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-1.6h-2.4c-0.4%200-0.7-0.3-0.8-0.6l-0.9-3.2h-1.9l1.7%205.8c0.7%202.4%202.8%204.1%205.2%204.4%202.2%200.3%204.8%200.3%207%200%202.5-0.3%204.5-2.1%205.2-4.4l1.8-5.8h-1.8z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Cpath%20d%3D%22m580%201153c-8.7%200-15.8%206.4-15.8%2014.4%200%204.1%201.8%207.7%204.8%2010.3h3.1c0.4%200%200.7%200.3%200.8%200.6l0.9%203.2h1.8v-1.6c0-0.5%200.4-0.9%200.9-0.9s0.9%200.4%200.9%200.9v1.6h1.8v-1.6c0-0.5%200.4-0.9%200.9-0.9s0.9%200.4%200.9%200.9v1.6h1.8v-1.6c0-0.5%200.4-0.9%200.9-0.9s0.9%200.4%200.9%200.9v1.6h1.8l0.9-3.2c0.1-0.4%200.5-0.6%200.8-0.6h3.1c3-2.6%204.8-6.3%204.8-10.3-0.2-8-7.2-14.4-16-14.4zm-8.7%2019.8c-2.4%200-3.2-1.4-3.2-3.8s1.9-4.3%204.3-4.3c4.4%200%204.8%202.5%204.3%204.3-0.5%202.1-3%203.8-5.4%203.8zm11.9%203.9c-0.8%200.9-1.9-1.7-3.1-1.6-1.3%200.1-2.3%202.5-3.1%201.6-0.3-0.3%201.4-5.4%203.1-5.4%201.8%200%203.3%205.1%203.1%205.4zm5.5-3.9c-2.4%200-4.9-1.7-5.4-3.8-0.5-1.8-0.1-4.3%204.3-4.3%202.4%200%204.3%201.9%204.3%204.3s-0.8%203.8-3.2%203.8z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3C%2Fg%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23c41a1e%22%20d%3D%22m522.9%201288c-2.1%204.1-7.1%205.7-11.2%203.7l-14.8-7.5c-8.2-4.2-11.5-14.2-7.3-22.4l29.6%2015c4.1%202.1%205.8%207.1%203.7%2011.2z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23ed1c24%22%20d%3D%22m535.8%201308h-10c-10.3%200-18.7-8.4-18.7-18.7v-37.2h28.7v55.9z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Ccircle%20cy%3D%221252%22%20cx%3D%22520.8%22%20r%3D%2215%22%20fill%3D%22%23ed1c24%22%3E%3C%2Fcircle%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%20d%3D%22m529.9%201252c0%205.1-4.1%209.2-9.2%209.2s-9.2-4.1-9.2-9.2%204.1-9.2%209.2-9.2%209.2%204.2%209.2%209.2z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23ed1c24%22%20d%3D%22m516%201238c3.3-3.3%209.6-3.6%2017.7-1.2l-3.4%203.9%204.6%201.1-5%203.5-13.9-7.3z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Crect%20height%3D%228%22%20width%3D%2211.3%22%20y%3D%221253%22%20x%3D%22509.5%22%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%0A%3Ccircle%20cy%3D%221257%22%20cx%3D%22507%22%20r%3D%226.3%22%20fill%3D%22%236d6e71%22%3E%3C%2Fcircle%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23414042%22%20d%3D%22m507.2%201248h-5.2c-3.4%200-6.1%202.7-6.1%206.1v3.4h17.5v-3.4c0-3.3-2.8-6.1-6.2-6.1z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Ccircle%20cy%3D%221252%22%20cx%3D%22520.8%22%20r%3D%223.3%22%20fill%3D%22%23414042%22%3E%3C%2Fcircle%3E%0A%3Ccircle%20cy%3D%221251%22%20cx%3D%22521.6%22%20r%3D%220.8%22%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%3E%3C%2Fcircle%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23c41a1e%22%20d%3D%22m535.8%201268c-1.5-1.1-3.3-1.7-5.3-1.7-5%200-9.1%204.1-9.1%209.1v18.1c0%206%202.9%2011.4%207.4%2014.7h6.9v-40z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23ed1c24%22%20d%3D%22m533.2%201266c-5%200-9.1%204.1-9.1%209.1v18.1c0%2010%208.1%2018.2%2018.2%2018.2v-36.3c-0.1-5-4.1-9.1-9.1-9.1z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3Crect%20height%3D%2213.3%22%20width%3D%2218.2%22%20y%3D%221280%22%20x%3D%22524.1%22%20fill%3D%22%23fff200%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%0A%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%231c75bc%22%20d%3D%22m542.2%201312v-18.2h-18.2c0.1%2010.1%208.2%2018.2%2018.2%2018.2z%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%0A%3C%2Fg%3E%0A%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
```

after decoding the same, I got this;

```
<img width="137" height="134" style="display: block;" src="data:image/svg xml,
<svg xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="134" width="137" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" viewBox="27.125 29 137.75 134">
    <g transform=" translate(19.976182752768793 22.142908647051712) scale(0.7536437893157988)">
        <g transform="translate(-137.8 -503.8)">
            <g transform="translate(-340 -622.5)">
                <path fill="#231f20" d="m620.8 1228h-11c-2.2-4.2-7.6-5.2-13.9-5.2-4.7 0-8.9 0.5-11.6 2.5-24.2-11.2-35.7-27-35.9-27.2-0.5-0.7-1.4-0.8-2-0.3-0.7 0.5-0.8 1.4-0.3 2 0.5 0.8 11.9 16.4 36.1 27.8-0.8 1.3-1.3 3-1.3 5.2 0 8.3 6.7 15 15 15s15-6.7 15-15c0-0.7-0.1-1.3-0.1-1.9h10.1c0.8 0 1.5-0.7 1.5-1.5-0.1-0.8-0.8-1.4-1.6-1.4z"></path>
                <path fill="#414042" d="m595.8 1240c-3.8 0-7.2-0.9-9.6-2.3 1.9 3.3 5.5 5.5 9.6 5.5s7.6-2.2 9.6-5.5c-2.4 1.4-5.8 2.3-9.6 2.3z"></path>
                <path fill="#231f20" d="m609.9 1160c-5.9-11.1-17.3-18-29.8-18s-24 6.9-29.8 18c-13.3 25.3-37.6 21.5-59 21.5 0 18.6 24.9 33.7 43.5 33.7 0 0 23.5-9.8 45.4-9.8s45.4 9.8 45.4 9.8c18.6 0 43.5-15.1 43.5-33.7-20.7 0.1-45.8 4.1-59.2-21.5z"></path>
                <path fill="#cca650" d="m550.2 1160c5.9-11.1 17.3-18 29.8-18s24 6.9 29.8 18c13.3 25.3 37.6 21.5 59 21.5v-5.9c-20.7 0-42.2 3.7-53.9-18.4-6.6-12.6-19.8-21.1-35-21.1s-28.4 8.6-35 21.1c-11.6 22-32.9 18.4-53.9 18.4v5.9c20.7 0.1 45.7 4.1 59.2-21.5z"></path>
                <g fill="#d1d3d4">
                    <path d="m588.6 1180-0.9 3.2c-0.1 0.4-0.5 0.6-0.8 0.6h-2.4v1.6c0 0.5-0.4 0.9-0.9 0.9s-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-1.6h-1.8v1.6c0 0.5-0.4 0.9-0.9 0.9s-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-1.6h-1.8v1.6c0 0.5-0.4 0.9-0.9 0.9s-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-1.6h-2.4c-0.4 0-0.7-0.3-0.8-0.6l-0.9-3.2h-1.9l1.7 5.8c0.7 2.4 2.8 4.1 5.2 4.4 2.2 0.3 4.8 0.3 7 0 2.5-0.3 4.5-2.1 5.2-4.4l1.8-5.8h-1.8z"></path>
                    <path d="m580 1153c-8.7 0-15.8 6.4-15.8 14.4 0 4.1 1.8 7.7 4.8 10.3h3.1c0.4 0 0.7 0.3 0.8 0.6l0.9 3.2h1.8v-1.6c0-0.5 0.4-0.9 0.9-0.9s0.9 0.4 0.9 0.9v1.6h1.8v-1.6c0-0.5 0.4-0.9 0.9-0.9s0.9 0.4 0.9 0.9v1.6h1.8v-1.6c0-0.5 0.4-0.9 0.9-0.9s0.9 0.4 0.9 0.9v1.6h1.8l0.9-3.2c0.1-0.4 0.5-0.6 0.8-0.6h3.1c3-2.6 4.8-6.3 4.8-10.3-0.2-8-7.2-14.4-16-14.4zm-8.7 19.8c-2.4 0-3.2-1.4-3.2-3.8s1.9-4.3 4.3-4.3c4.4 0 4.8 2.5 4.3 4.3-0.5 2.1-3 3.8-5.4 3.8zm11.9 3.9c-0.8 0.9-1.9-1.7-3.1-1.6-1.3 0.1-2.3 2.5-3.1 1.6-0.3-0.3 1.4-5.4 3.1-5.4 1.8 0 3.3 5.1 3.1 5.4zm5.5-3.9c-2.4 0-4.9-1.7-5.4-3.8-0.5-1.8-0.1-4.3 4.3-4.3 2.4 0 4.3 1.9 4.3 4.3s-0.8 3.8-3.2 3.8z"></path>
                </g>
                <path fill="#c41a1e" d="m522.9 1288c-2.1 4.1-7.1 5.7-11.2 3.7l-14.8-7.5c-8.2-4.2-11.5-14.2-7.3-22.4l29.6 15c4.1 2.1 5.8 7.1 3.7 11.2z"></path>
                <path fill="#ed1c24" d="m535.8 1308h-10c-10.3 0-18.7-8.4-18.7-18.7v-37.2h28.7v55.9z"></path>
                <circle cy="1252" cx="520.8" r="15" fill="#ed1c24"></circle>
                <path fill="#fff" d="m529.9 1252c0 5.1-4.1 9.2-9.2 9.2s-9.2-4.1-9.2-9.2 4.1-9.2 9.2-9.2 9.2 4.2 9.2 9.2z"></path>
                <path fill="#ed1c24" d="m516 1238c3.3-3.3 9.6-3.6 17.7-1.2l-3.4 3.9 4.6 1.1-5 3.5-13.9-7.3z"></path>
                <rect height="8" width="11.3" y="1253" x="509.5" fill="#fff"></rect>
                <circle cy="1257" cx="507" r="6.3" fill="#6d6e71"></circle>
                <path fill="#414042" d="m507.2 1248h-5.2c-3.4 0-6.1 2.7-6.1 6.1v3.4h17.5v-3.4c0-3.3-2.8-6.1-6.2-6.1z"></path>
                <circle cy="1252" cx="520.8" r="3.3" fill="#414042"></circle>
                <circle cy="1251" cx="521.6" r="0.8" fill="#fff"></circle>
                <path fill="#c41a1e" d="m535.8 1268c-1.5-1.1-3.3-1.7-5.3-1.7-5 0-9.1 4.1-9.1 9.1v18.1c0 6 2.9 11.4 7.4 14.7h6.9v-40z"></path>
                <path fill="#ed1c24" d="m533.2 1266c-5 0-9.1 4.1-9.1 9.1v18.1c0 10 8.1 18.2 18.2 18.2v-36.3c-0.1-5-4.1-9.1-9.1-9.1z"></path>
                <rect height="13.3" width="18.2" y="1280" x="524.1" fill="#fff200"></rect>
                <path fill="#1c75bc" d="m542.2 1312v-18.2h-18.2c0.1 10.1 8.2 18.2 18.2 18.2z"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>">
```

So what is this? What is the role of XML here? how can I retrieve that image?

Answer (score 1):

The XML is a SVG vector graphic, you can copy the XML code and put it in a text editor and save it as SVG and reopen it in graphic program or you use a SVG to canvas service:

http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/